# WPF MouseMove event fires before Loaded

Tags: wpf, mousemove, loaded

In my window, I have a UserControl that is dynamically created. I subscribe to two events of this UserControl: `Loaded` and `MouseMove`. In `Loaded` I create an `AdornerLayer` from `UserControl`, and in `MouseMove` I use this layer to add and remove particular adorners. But strangely, `MouseMove` event fires **before** `Loaded` and because of it my `_adornerLayer` instance is null, since it is not set yet.

Why is it happening? What is the right sequence of events to get `_adornerLayer` ready before any mouse events?

Comment: The Loaded-Event is fired when: "The Loaded event says that the tree is not only built and initialized, but layout has run on it, data has been bound, it's connected to a rendering surface (window), and you're on the verge of being rendered." (Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx). A possible solution could be to subscribe to the "MouseMove" Event in a method handling the "Loaded" Event. Also why do you create your AdornerLayer in the Loaded Event and not e.g. in the Constructor of the UserControl?

Comment: Because it is impossible to create AdornerLayer on a control that is not fully loaded (or shown). I used to call `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer` straight after UserControl creation, but it returned null, so I had to postpone this call to Loaded event.